# is bad habit to don't use foreign in migration laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

I am new in laravel. In my tutorial video teacher use **foreign** in migration but,i can create my relationships without it and use just  **belongTo** and **hasMany**.When i use foreign can not delete one post easily (error is you can not delete because parent foreign has child ......).
my question is my way is good or not? and why?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is good but I think foreign keys are better.  Had you not had that foreign key, you would have deleted the post but all that post's children (referred to as orphans because they no longer have a parent) would have stuck around.  In order to get around the foreign key error, you would need to first delete all the children for that post, and then delete the post.

The good news is foreign keys can also do this for you so you don't need to worry about keeping track of all the children.  When you setup the foreign key, if you add the `on delete cascade` clause, when deleting the post, the database would automatically remove all of the posts's children for you and deleting a post without first deleting the children would no longer result in an error.

If it's your preference to keep the children around even when the post is deleted, you can use `on delete set null` instead which would simply set the children's foreign key to null rather than delete the record.

This is all useful for enforcing data integrity (databases should contain only accurate and valid data).

Answer (score 1):

The answer really is not 'is this good practice in Laravel' so much as 'is this good practice for database management'.

There are many articles on the topic as to the good and bad side of using foreign keys. Here is a good explanation on the DBA stack exchange

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168590/not-using-foreign-key-constraints-in-real-practice-is-it-ok

My personal preference is to use them to maintain data integrity. The real power comes in adding cascading deletes to the relationship (if applicable to your design).

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to how good you want your database to be.The main reasons to use foreign keys in your database are

- To prevent actions that would destroy links between your tables
- This would prevent the invalid data from being inserted to the foreign key column as it has to point to a existing value
- Also defining foreign keys makes your query faster depending on database I don't know the exact milliseconds but if I find it out I will post it.

Well from the laravel point of view the way you do is a better way as this is how one of the main teacher of the Laravel(Jeffrey Way) teaches in the getting started with laravel series.

- Foreign Keys are the way to define relationship between tables in your database whereas Laravel `belongsTo()` or `hasMany()` is a way to define relationship between tables in Laravel